# How can I show this enum description as a tooltip for each enum in my view.(DotnetCore).I have tried adding the DescriptionAttribute but getts error

Tags: c#, .net-core

The type or namespace name 'DescriptionAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
  public class Test
        {
            public Test()
            {
            }
           
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [Required]
           
    
            [Display(Name = "Shape")]
            public Shapes? Shape { get; set; } 
    
        }
    
        public enum Shapes
        {
            [DescriptionAttribute("A shape with 3 strokes")]
            Triangle,
    
            [DescriptionAttribute("A rounded shape")]
            Circle,
    
            [DescriptionAttribute("A shape with 4 corners")]
            Square,
    
            Other
        }
```

Comment: Isn't it just called `Description('<some Description>')` from the namespace `System.ComponentModel`?

Comment: @sschwei1 yes I arleady have System.ComponentModel  in my imports

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supposed to just use Display attribute and not Description attribute. Check this link (see the remarks section)

[Display Data Annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.description?view=net-6.0#system-componentmodel-dataannotations-displayattribute-description)